# How to use a callback function in a class with inheritance

Tags: javascript, typescript, oop, callback

How can I use a method from the parent in a child method that is used as a callback function

```js
class Parent {
    numbers: number[];

    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    protected iterateNumbers(iterCallback: (nb: number) => void): void {
        for (const nb of this.numbers) {
            iterCallback(nb);
        }
    }

    protected inc(nb: number): number {
        return nb++;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        super(numbers)
    }

    getNumbers(): void {
        this.iterateNumbers(this.displayNumber);
    }

    private displayNumber(nb: number): void {
        console.log(this.inc(nb));
    }
}

const c = new Child([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
c.getNumbers();
```

This code results in this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'inc' of undefined`

modified with super()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a way to do the same thing but with a none static method

ES6 style allows you to use new features, such as super keyword. super keyword it's all about parent class context, when you are using ES6 classes syntax.

```js
class Parent {
    numbers: number[];

    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    protected iterateNumbers(predictionCallback: (nb: number) => void): void {
        for (const nb of this.numbers) {
            predictionCallback(nb);
        }
    }

    protected inc(nb: number): number {
        return nb++;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {

    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        super(numbers)
    }

    getNumbers() {
        this.iterateNumbers(this.displayNumber);
    }

    private displayNumber(nb: number): void {
        console.log(super.inc(nb));
    }
}

const c = new Child([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
c.getNumbers();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the super method in the constructor of the child class in order to access properties and methods of the super class.

Also, as you have the `displayNumber` method private you will not be able to access it from an object created from the `child` class. Removing the private keyword would allow access

Try changing your extended child to include the constructor method and super call:

```js
class Child extends Parent {

    constructor() {
        super()
    }
    
    getNumbers(): void {
        this.iterateNumbers(this.displayNumber);
    }

    displayNumber(nb: number): void {
        console.log(this.inc(nb));
    }
}
```

You can read more in the [MDN docs on the super keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super)

UPDATE:

After testing a little I have found a solution to why you are getting that error, of course it's all about context. If you make the `inc` method static you will be able to call it by `Parent.inc()`

By passing the `displayNumber` method in as a callback you are loosing the context of the class you are wanting to call it from. This is why you get the undefined error.

```js
class Parent {
    numbers: number[];

    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    protected iterateNumbers(iterCallback: (nb: number) => void): void {
        for (const nb of this.numbers) {
            iterCallback(nb);
        }
    }

    static inc(nb: number): number {
        return nb++;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    constructor(numbers: number[]) {
        super(numbers)
    }

    getNumbers(): void {
        this.iterateNumbers(this.displayNumber);
    }

    private displayNumber(nb: number): void {
        console.log(Parent.inc(nb));
    }
}

const c = new Child([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
c.getNumbers(); // prints 1 2 3 4 5
```

If you run this code you will see the numbers printed out.

Now by using both calling the super method in the `child` constructor and updating the `inc` method to be static, and calling it as such, I think you will get the expected results.

Comment: I've modified the code but it still don't works I was able to access this.iterateNumbers() in  getNumbers() the first time but not in the displayNumber() method

Comment: I have updated my answer, since it is private you wont be able to access it

Comment: protected is not the issue

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that wrong. I believe it is because you have the displayNumber as private. Try it without the private keyword

Comment: It's not this sorry, can you please test the code before answering me :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to include use of the `static` keyword and why you were getting undefined